# How to download file in the format as it was uploaded on Odoo-server?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have written the following code that uploads A CSV file on Odoo 10 server. But when I see the file size it shows in "B" not in "Kb".

**This is py code:**

```
csv_file = fields.Binary(string="CSV Export", readonly=True, default='')
csv_filename = fields.Char("", size=256)
```

**This is tree view code:**

```
<field name="csv_file" filename="csv_filename" string="Result"/>
<field name="csv_filename" invisible="1"/>
```

File is getting uploaded properly no doubt about it. but when I am downloading that file it either showing server error or downloading file in binary. Help me to correct my mess please (my Odoo version is 10).

Comment: Look at the comment and don't forget to upvote and verify if it goes right !

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
<field name="csv_file" filename="csv_filename" widget="download_link" string="Result"/>
```

Comment: I cannot find a `download_link` widget in Odoo 10 community edition. If the widget comes from an additional addon, please provide a source link.